# Typescript: Disabling es-lint rule for only an interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I have the rule in my project to disallow variables not in camelcase.  I am hitting an external API where the response comes back with an object that has variables in camelcase.  When I define a type:

```
interface AgeData {
    name: string,
    corner: number
}

interface APIResp {
    file_name: string,
    data_info: AgeData[],
    interest_m: number
}
```

I need to use camelcase for the expected format back from the API since I can't control the external API.
Throughout the rest of my code, I use:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
```

to disable it but this doesn't seem to work for interfaces.
I don't want to change the rule or override it.  It's a fairly large project and I just want it this one interface.

Comment: Are you sure that it's the `camelcase` rule that is complaining? What exactly is the error/warning message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [`camelcase`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/camelcase) can be as type-aware as you're hoping for, but what it *can* do is:

- Permit property names to have underscores (or forbid property names to have underscores). This is separate from permitting standalone identifiers from having underscores. Or
- Permit *specific whitelisted property names* even if they don't match the pattern.

So, one way is to use the following config for the ESLint rule:

```
[
  'error',
  {
    allow: ['file_name', 'data_info', 'interest_m']
  }
]
```